# how do I handle an event ONLY when another event has been handled in socket.io

Tags: socket.io

okay so i have two events and two event handlers. event A and handler A and likewise with B.
event A and event B can be emitted independently. however, event B can only be handled if event A has been handled.

so this would mean that, event B can be emitted but it'll never be handled,
if event A hasnt been.

i've tried to write handler B inside handler A but apparently, event B still gets handled just fine, my rule fails. so writing one handler inside another does nothing.

is there a way to make this happen.

```
socket.current.on("eventA", (data) => {
            console.log("A get handle");

            setArrivedtext({conversationId: data.converid});  // irrelevant state


            socket.current.on("eventB",(data)=>{

                console.log(B get handled);
   
            });
                    
});
```